# Chrome extension update notification

Tags: google-chrome

How to show notification when chrome extension updates automatically?
My requirement is to show a popup after update the chrome extension automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome extension auto update event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335541/chrome-extension-auto-update-event)

Answer (score 4):

There is a [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled` event](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/runtime.html#event-onInstalled) you can listen to that fires when the extension is installed or updated ([so says the new packaged app documentation](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/apps/app_lifecycle.html#H3-6)), <s>but it's only available in the dev channel right now.</s>

**2019 Update:** Since this answer was provided in 2012, this event has been moved from the dev to the stable channel.

Comment: The second link is obsolete. Can you give a simple example: how to open the popup window when the extension is updated?

Comment: Well, the link to `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` is really all you need. I wouldn't suggest opening a popup window on update because that's really annoying, but it would be something like this:

    `chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
      if (details.reason == "update") {
        chrome.windows.create({url: "popup.html", type: "popup"});
      }
    });`

Comment: The link to chrome.runtime.onInstalled has rotted. Google redirects it to something impossible now. (https://code.google.com/https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/dev/runtime.html) Here's an updated link: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled

Answer (score 3):

Here is the complete answer and it is working for me.

```
//=============== background.js =================
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
  try {
    var thisVersion = chrome.runtime.getManifest().version;
    if (details.reason == "install") {
      console.info("First version installed");
      //Send message to popup.html and notify/alert user("Welcome")
    } else if (details.reason == "update") {
      console.info("Updated version: " + thisVersion);
      //Send message to popup.html and notify/alert user

      chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
        for( var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++ ) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {name: "showPopupOnUpdated", version: thisVersion});
        }
        });
    }
  } catch(e) {
    console.info("OnInstall Error - " + e);
  }
});


//=============== popup.js =================
//Note: this has to be injected as content script from manifest.json
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    switch (request.name) {
        case "showPopupOnUpdated":
            alert("Extension got updated to latest version: " + request.version);
            break;
    }
});


//=============== manifest.js =================
//Note: background.html needs to import background.js
{
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "js/popup.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope it helps.